# Sorting 2-D Array Python Outputing as array within an array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

So I'm trying to sort an array like this by the third item in the array:

```
[[591 756   3]
 [296 669   7]
 [752 560   2]
 [476 474   0]
 [214 459   1]
 [845 349   6]
 [122 145   4]
 [476 125   5]
 [766 110   8]]
```

so it would look like

```
[[476 474   0]
 [214 459   1]
 [752 560   2]
 [591 756   3]
 ....and so on]
```

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
sortedanswers = sorted(answithcpoints,key=lambda x:x[2])
```

but printing sortedanswers would output something like

```
[array([476, 474,   0]), array([214, 459,   1]), array([752, 560,   2]), array([591, 756,   3]), array([122, 145,   4]), array([476, 125,   5]), array([845, 349,   6]), array([296, 669,   7]), array([766, 110,   8])]
```

seems to be some sort of array inside the array?

Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: Numpy array? You can argsort on the last column and re-index.

Comment: Your desired output is also a structure of arrays within an array; what do you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with numpy arrays, don't bring `sorted` into this. Call [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on the last column, and use the sorted indices to re-arrange the array -

```
arr[arr[:, -1].argsort()]

array([[476, 474,   0],
       [214, 459,   1],
       [752, 560,   2],
       [591, 756,   3],
       [122, 145,   4],
       [476, 125,   5],
       [845, 349,   6],
       [296, 669,   7],
       [766, 110,   8]])
```

---

- `arr[:, -1]` grabs the last column from `arr`

  ```
  arr[:, -1]
  array([3, 7, 2, 0, 1, 6, 4, 5, 8])
  ```
- `arr[:, -1].argsort()` - sorts `arr`'s last column based on its indices. The result is an array of sorted indices of `x`

  ```
  arr[:, -1].argsort()
  array([3, 4, 2, 0, 6, 7, 5, 1, 8])
  ```
- `arr[arr[:, -1].argsort()]` indexes rows in `arr` based on the contents of the sorted indices from the previous step

Comment: this worked wonderfully thank you! for education purposes, would you mind explaining the line a little bit? what does array[:,-1] actually mean?